# Question with conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

You ask a neighbor to water a sickly plant while you are on vacation. Without water the plant will die with probability 0.9. With water it will die with probability 0.5. You are 87 % certain the neighbor will remember to water the plant.

When you are on vacation, find the probability that the plant will die. 
Ok so for this I was thinking you just multiply.9 x .5 to get .45 from an example I have seen. Why would this be wrong?

You come back from the vacation and the plant is dead. What is the probability the neighbor forgot to water it?

This is what I have done and it keeps coming back wrong. P(neighbor forgets|plant dies w/o water) = (1-.87)(.9) = .117

What do I keep doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, I got the first one. .552

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The plant dying while you're on vacation happens *if either*:

1. The neighbor waters it but it dies
2. The neighbors forgets to water and then it dies.

The probabilities for each are different, and they need to be added together.

Edit: For the second bit, recall the formula $$P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$ So we need to find P(neighbor forgets | plant dies) = P(neighbor forgets and plant dies) / P(plant dies). Can you complete it now?

Comment: Thank you! I understood that just as I saw this!And you need the first one to answer the second one correct? Like if I was only asked the probability that neighbor forgot and the plant died, I would still need the total probability it died?

Comment: You're welcome. For the second bit, see my edit. As for your question, to find the probability of the plant dying and the neighbor forgetting is $(0.13)(0.9)$. No need for any other probabilities.

Comment: Yes, thanks again. I got .212

Comment: Is that what you were expecting?